# Use PostGIS to retrieve the nearby points

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I've tried to use PostGIS to retrieve the nearby points, however, 
I've gotten an error message from the pgAdmin3.
Can you help me to debug the SQL queries (Postgresql+PostGIS) below?
Thank you for your kindness help.

I've used the 3826 geometry.

"ERROR:  parse error - invalid geometry
HINT:  "...79721.29349234176 2759680.13418412))" <-- parse error at position 44 within geometry" in the

```
    SELECT *  FROM pointslight

    WHERE ST_DWithin(

            ST_Transform(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(279721.29349234176 2759680.13418412))',3826),26986),
            ST_Transform(location,26986), 50)
            ORDER BY ST_Distance(ST_GeomFromText('POINT(279721.29349234176 2759680.13418412))',3826), location);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the string defining the point, you have one opening parenthesis an two closing one. Remove one of the latter!